# How to change the width of the UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on a `UITableView` which has a `SwipeGesture`.
On Swipe, the Cell should Swipe Left and the objects which are set at 320 should appear

Comment: try to read this tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views
 This will clear your all doubts and problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place them in the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell` and make an animation on the `contentView` that changes the frame to x = -320 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` change the frame of cells when they are added to the table view. If you want to change the width of a cell, you should either change the width of the table, or change the width of the contentView in the cell.

A better way to achieve this is subclassing `UITableViewCell` and overriding its `-setFrame:` method like this:

Try this one:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame  
{
  frame.origin.x += inset;
  frame.size.width -= 2 * inset;
  [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Comment: getting an error "**No visible interface for UITableViewController declares the selector setFrame:**"

Comment: otherwise u have to adding a view on cell and when u want to left swipe that time u have to animate that view from right to left

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
    // Create the swipe view

    //Change the frame as per your requirement

   UIView* _swipeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 10, 70)];       
    //setting the background
    [_swipeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [_swipeView setTag:1896];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_swipeView];        

    // Create the gesture recognizers
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeRightInCell:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeLeftInCell:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

> >

```
    -(void) didSwipeRightInCell:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)ges{
        UITableViewCell* cellViewInProgress_ = (UITableViewCell*)ges.view;

        for(UIView* view in cellViewInProgress.contentView.subviews)
        {
            if(view.tag == 1896){
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

//Change the frame as per your requirement
                    view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 220, 70);
                }];

    // I have placed UILabel you can try your own control

//Change the frame as per your requirement

                UILabel *lblDemo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 200, 30)];
                [lblDemo setFont:[Support getAppFontSemiBold:16.0]];
                [lblDemo setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [lblDemo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                lblDemo.tag = 2341;
                [lblDemo setText:@"Hello"]];
                [view addSubview:lblDemo];

            }
        }
    }
```

> >

```
  -(void)  didSwipeLeftInCell :(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)ges{
        UITableViewCell* cellViewInProgress_ = (UITableViewCell*)ges.view;

        for(UIView* view in cellViewInProgress.contentView.subviews)
        {
            if(view.tag == 1896){
                UILabel* lbl = (UILabel*)[view viewWithTag:2341];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
//Change the frame as per your requirement

                    view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 10, 70);
                    [lbl removeFromSuperview];
                }];
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.